# FormClosed Event Not Called When Main Form Closes

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be notified when a `Form` in my program closes so that I can save the state of its child controls and then restore those control states the next time the form is opened.  I put the code to save control state in the form's `FormClosing` method.  However, if the main form gets closed instead of closing the form that I'm saving control state for, then the form's `FormClosing` method never gets called before the program exits.  Where should I put my code to guarantee that it gets called either when the form is directly closed, or when the main form is closed instead?

Comment: The form's Dispose(bool) method is good, it is called either way.  Cut and paste it from the Designer.cs file.  Don't do anything when *disposing* is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the child form is "owned" by the main form when you go to show it:

```
childForm.Show(this);
```